# Android: Costum layout in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have a ListView with a custom adapter and it uses a custom layout:

```
package giorag.rottentomatoexampleapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class ShortMovieDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShortMovie> {

    public ShortMovieDataAdapter(Context context, int resource, ShortMovie[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        ShortMovie movie = getItem(position);

        MovieHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.short_movie_data_view, parent, false);

            holder = new MovieHolder();
            holder.movieTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_title);
            holder.year = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_year);
            holder.type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_type);
            holder.imdb = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_imdb_id);
            holder.poster = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_data_poster);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (MovieHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.movieTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.year .setText(movie.getYear());
        holder.type.setText(movie.getType());
        holder.imdb.setText(movie.getImdbID());
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(movie.getPoster()).into(holder.poster);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

    static class MovieHolder {
        public TextView movieTitle;
        public TextView year;
        public TextView type;
        public TextView imdb;
        public ImageView poster;
    }
}
```

And that is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/movie_title_placeholder"
                android:id="@+id/short_data_title"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/year_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/year_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_year"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/type_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/type_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_type"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/imdb_id_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/imdb_id_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_imdb_id"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/short_data_poster"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

That is my problem:

[image: Problem with layout]

Instead of being attached to the right hand side of the container, the ImageView is always next to the rest of the views.

How do I get the ImageView to always be on the right hand side?

--- EDIT ---

Thanks to Farham! that worked. But now I have several more issues.
First is that the ImageView is not stretched to the height of the View,
And second, the last item in the ListView is partially showing:

[image: New problem]

I can't scroll lower than what's showed in the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **replace** the **FrameLayout** with **RelativeLayout** (the parent of all views), then add the **ImageView** and set **layout_alignParentRight="true"**.

And the **top most LinearLayout** which contains all other views, should always be **aligned with the left of the relativeLayout** and **the left of the imageView.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Farhad! That worked, but now I have another issue. The ImageView is not stretched to the whole height of the view, and also, I've had this before, the last item in the item view is only partially showing. I'll post a new image now

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use `RelativeLayout` and set layout_alignParentRight="true" for you ImageView.

Or you can change `android:layout_width` to `0dp` for inner `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:layout_weight="2">
```

......

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/short_data_poster"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relative Layout or if you want to Linear Layout use your weights effectively. If you use `android:weight="2"//or something else` your width should be zero dp. `android:width="0dp"` (for a horizontal layout and android:height="0" if you are using vertical layout). Your layout should look like this:

```
              <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp" //note this
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                   <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear layout to achieve this, copy paste this code and see if it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/movie_title_placeholder"
                android:id="@+id/short_data_title"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/year_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/year_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_year"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/type_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/type_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_type"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/imdb_id_label"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/imdb_id_label"
                    android:id="@+id/short_data_imdb_id"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/short_data_poster"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```